# Program seems to hang only when NOT debugging in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, infinite-loop

In the script I've created, when I run it normally, seems to hang or get stuck or end up in an infinite loop.  I placed a couple of breakpoints throughout my code to step through it to try find where the problem is, but when I run it in the debugger, there aren't any issues!

I've dug around online about this a little, but can't find anything.  Probably more of an issue of not putting in the correct search criteria, but in any event, I'm stuck.

Ok, so I think I've found the region that the problem lies in.  Here is the code:

```
function inductDaycareIntoSystem(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var controlRoomSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();  // alias for master doc sheet
  var daycareNumber = chooseADaycare();  // Holds the number entry for the daycare chosen to work on (the starting entry, when doing multiple daycares) col. A
  Logger.log("Line 5");
  var finalDaycareNumber = daycareNumber; //  Holds the last daycare slot number to be processed (same number as 'daycareNumber' when only one is being processed)
      //Needs to be adjusted to get a final number as well

  for(var i = daycareNumber; i >= finalDaycareNumber; i ++){

     **code to execute in loop**
  }
```

The program still seems to hang with all the code inside the for loop commented out.

Comment: Still, post (please, no screenshots) the code in the question (try to keep things [minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), though) - it will imrpove your chances to get help. "separating each 'file' with a line of asterisks" - I hope these are comment lines? And what stopped you from creating several files in the first place? While deciding what is relevant, you may find the problem yourself. Try to pinpoint the issue - add `console` statements, comment out such lines and test, etc (if you think there is a loop - take a look at the breaking conditions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Think about what you are doing

- Let's assume `daycareNumber = 2`
- Since `var finalDaycareNumber = daycareNumber;` - `finalDaycareNumber` will also be `2`
- For your loop it means:
   `for(var i = 2; i >= 2; i ++){`
- In words: Start with `i =2` and increase i`in every iteration as long as`i`is not smaller than`2`
- But `i` will never be smaller than `2`, since `2` is the start value and from there on `i` will only increase in each iteration

Comment: So if I understand correctly, I have the wrong sign in my for loop?
wow.  Rookie mistake.  
Thank you for all your help.  You take your time to read through my (probably not so efficient) code and it helps me.  Thank you.

Comment: Not just the wrong sign, but the wrong logic. From your code it is not clear what exactly you want to do and what `chooseADaycare()` does. But if you want to loop from 0 to a final value and your final value is `finalDayCareNumber`, your loop should be something like `for(var i = 0; i < finalDaycareNumber; i ++){`

Comment: Thank you @ziganotschka.  I have a listing of daycares that cover multiple lines, and I did not want to loop through all of them.  ChooseADaycare selects the index of the first daycare sought, and finalDaycareNumber selects the last one.
So if I have 10 entries, each 'slot' for an entry is 4 rows, and I want to process only entries 4 - 7, 4 would be the starting daycare number, and 7 the final one.
Thanks for the help!